# Large Covariance Matrix

Tags: python-2.7, idl-programming-language

How do I calculate a reliable covariance matrix from a 256x520x218 hyperspectral image? The image has 218 spectral channels so each single band image is 256x520. I'm interested in calculating covariance over each pixel not each band.

Comment: You've tagged your question with both IDL and Python.  In what language do you seek a solution?

Comment: IDL preferably. I could get an answer in python and try to translate to IDL. Much prefer IDL :)